# Why can't I send an array of data in jQuery ajax/post?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this JavaScript source:

```
var mydata = [];

$('.myManyElements').each(function() {
    mydata.push({
        'id': $(this).data('id'),
        'quantity': $(this).data('quantity'),
        'price': $(this).data('price'),
        'price_total': Order.getTotalPrice()
    });
});

$.post('/archive', mydata, function(data) {
    if(data.success) {
        alert(data.response);
    } else {
        alert('Custom Error Report!');
    }
}, 'json');
```

And in my `/archive` request I have this sample PHP:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'success' => true,
    'response' => print_r($_POST, true),
));
```

When I check Firebug's NET panel for XHR, in the POST tab it says that I've sent this:

```
undefined=
```

When I get my response in my `alert` it outputs:

```
Array
(
    [undefined] => 
)
```

---

**Why can't I send an array of data for my POST request?**

Comment: How did you expect it to be sent? There's no standard way to send an array of objects...

Comment: jQuery can achive this as I can recall...

Comment: as it says in the jquery docs: _If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below)._ — see at: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax

Comment: Note how it says "based on the value of the `traditional` setting"? Set that to `true` :) (It's not on by default, probably because that's an *incorrect* serialization.)

Comment: @minitech please read my last comment, before this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$.post('/archive', {'mydata': JSON.stringify(mydata)}, function(data)
```

Comment: well this works perfectly like in a Dream... this will do the job :) thanks! accepting after a few min's!

Comment: Why are you using `JSON.stringify`?  It should work just as `{mydata: mydata}`.

Comment: Because that way you get it as JSON on the backend, and my understanding is that this is what the OP is about..